# Flutter iOS app not calling api in TestFlight build

Tags: ios, flutter, http, testflight

I have an application by which i'm uploading a pdf file in server through http multi-part form data. in response server give response. in the meantime, users see a loader in the screen.

Everything works as it is supposed to in development time. But when I upload the build in TestFlight and test from TestFlight it doesn't actually show any loader, which means the api is not calling.

I'm using https protocol in the server as well. But no result.
Can anyone tell me what's the issue here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use `flutter run --release` with `flutter logs` to print logs at every point to check what is happening in the release mode of your app. You will require a real device for this.

Comment: how can i see logs while running with "flutter run --release"? @Pokaboom

Comment: Connect your device with a USB cable and run  `flutter run --release` and along with it in another terminal of your IDE run `flutter logs` it will print logs even for release mode. But  you have to use `print` as `debugPrint` won't work

Answer (score 0):

IN CASE YOU DIDN'T ADD THE PERMISSION. THIS WAS MY CASE

Adding the **internet permission** is necessary in order for your app to access the internet and communicate with servers or APIs. Make sure to add the internet permission to your AndroidManifest.xml file like this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application ... >
    ...
</application>
```

In addition, if you are using iOS, make sure to enable the **App Sandbox** capability in your Xcode project, which includes the "Outgoing Connections (Client)" entitlement. This is necessary for your app to make outgoing network connections on iOS.

With these steps, your app should be able to access the internet and communicate with servers without any issues.

Comment: The asker stated that it works in development, so likely the permissions are already there.

Comment: @Cristik it works at development stage even if the permissions are not granted. I have tested it on both android & iOS.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).